# Visual C++ accepts One point decimal

Tags: visual-c++

I have a calculator in visual c++, and I want to press a button of point, example  1.2 point , but if the number already has a point don't accept more

```
String^ punto;
String^ dato = lblDatos->Text;
bool point = false;
if (lblDatos->TextLength > 0)
  { 
  punto = dato + ".";
  lblDatos->Text = punto;
  }
```

Comment: Please provide code showing what you have tried.

Comment: String^ punto;
 String^ dato = lblDatos->Text;
 bool point = false;
 if (lblDatos->TextLength > 0)
 {
  punto = dato + ".";
  lblDatos->Text = punto;
 
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before adding the point, check the text to see if it already contains a point.

```
if ((lblDatos->TextLength > 0) && !(lblDatos->Text->Contains(".")) {
    lblDatos->Text = lblDatos->Text + ".";
}
```